# Since I upgraded my MacBook Air (Retina, 13-inch, 2020) to Catalina, I am getting this error; fans are getting crazy

Tags: macbook-pro, catalina

#1 System log results among others:

```
22 Feb 2024, 4:59:00 PM  com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: Failed to bootstrap path: path = /usr/libexec/remindd, error = 108: Invalid path
```

Any idea what this error means?

#2. Mac fans too loud.

I shutdown every night now in order to let the MBA cool down. Besides these two, system and battery are OK.

Do you think it would be better to maybe proceed with next upgrade to Sonoma in order to fix both malfunctions or it is out of the question because it is new OS and needs to be tested further?

Comment: 10.15 Catalina is the original macOS version for that machine, so you've just updated *within* 10.15, yes?

Comment: Thanks for your reply!No, actually I got it with macOS Big Sur, then I upgraded to macOS Ventura and recently to Catalina, so no

Comment: So you've downgraded, why? The sequence is Catalina, Big Sur, Monterey, Ventura, Sonoma. You may have later firmware which is incompatible with Catalina.

Comment: YES, you are right! However, this was the next proposed version to upgrade automatically by Apple. Anyways I am planning to move to Monterey and if Apple gives the green light move to Ventura, many thanks for your help!

Comment: Ventura is the latest version of macOS. Apple has given the 'green light' to Ventura. We told our users (>500 individuals) to update to Ventura months ago, after we tested all our crucial apps. No reason not to unless you have apps which won't run under Ventura.

Comment: Also - do you use the Reminders app? That specific error relates to the reminders daemon which runs in the background.

Comment: Yes, I am using Reminders app in the background, good to know!

Comment: @IconDaemon did you mean Sonoma?

Comment: `/usr/libexec/remindd` is the Reminders daemon which runs in the background. The error message points to remindd daemon having a problem. I don't use Reminders, yet remindd is running on my Sonoma macs (4 at this point.)

Comment: I see, meantime it seems I managed to resolve the CPU temperature reaching 97+ degrees. I started closing all open tabs in chrome and then, I realised there was one application open, the hub.cards. As soon as I quit this application, temperature reduced -127 degrees immediately!

Answer (score 0):

Check you CPU, Thermal and Fan in Terminal before sleep

sudo powermetrics --samplers smc |grep -i "CPU die temperature" (should be around 60C)

sudo powermetrics --samplers smc |grep -i "thermal"

sudo powermetrics --samplers smc |grep -i "fan"

Use control C to stop it

Comment: Will do, thanks!

Comment: Last login: Thu Feb 22 04:25:53 on console
a2179@192 ~ % 
a2179@192 ~ % sudo powermetrics --samplers smc |grep -i "CPU die temperature" 
Password:

CPU die temperature: 86.38 C
CPU die temperature: 84.95 C
CPU die temperature: 84.08 C
CPU die temperature: 83.45 C
CPU die temperature: 83.47 C
CPU die temperature: 83.64 C
CPU die temperature: 85.66 C
CPU die temperature: 85.48 C
CPU die temperature: 84.32 C
CPU die temperature: 84.43 C
CPU die temperature: 85.31 C
CPU die temperature: 87.83 C
CPU die temperature: 86.03 C

Comment: @LIA that is a hot one, that is why the fan is running. What is your Mac doing to heat up CPU ? Use the Activity Monitor to see who is consuming CPU, then we can talk more

Comment: I am using Chrome for a specific application, thank you

Comment: It seems that, I managed to resolve the CPU temperature reaching 97+ degrees. I started closing all open tabs in chrome and then, I realised there was one application open, the hub.cards. As soon as I quit this application, temperature reduced -127 degrees immediately!

Comment: Great, hope you learned few tricks along the way, like monitoring CPU temperature without installing fancy apps for that

Comment: Yay! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @LIA and no reward for me ?